# Wordpress cookie issue on login: “ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.”

Tags: headers, cookies, wp-login-form

recently I had the problem where on login page Wordpress reported an error:

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must
>   enable cookies to use WordPress.

This was asked several times here and also on other platforms. I have pinned it down to my custom plugin. Deleting the contents of the php file didn't solve but only renaming it. I pinned down the error to `headers_sent()` check in `wp-login.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some empty spaces in custom plugin outside of `<?php ... ?>` enclosure. This is not a specific issue for cookies and the error is misleading. My custom plugin was only a single php file with 2 extra empty lines. The existing popular question about the same error message doesn't include any answers regarding empty lines. The question is also protected by the community. That is why, I needed to answer in a separate question.